# LaTeX Documentation containing the classes and functions and definition for each

Tags: documentation

Is there a LaTeX Documentation similar to Java Documentation, showing the packages, the classes to use and a sample example?

Comment: Actually, almost every packages and document classes was distributed with its documentation in your TeX distribution. You can type `texdoc <package or documentclass name>` in system terminal window to find them. However, since the packages were written by many different authors, there is not and will not be a document that shows how to use all of them. Fortunatelly, tutorials, such as 'lshort.pdf' (`texdoc lshort` to open it) and [The LaTeX Companion](http://www.amazon.com/LaTeX-Companion-Techniques-Computer-Typesetting/dp/0201362996), introduce most frequent used packages and documentclasses.

Comment: Hi Soni, Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, this is going to be a long discussion.

> I don't know what are the packages a full `miktex` has?

You can find all the packages installed in the folder `C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex` for miktex. There must be a similar folder for `texlive` too, but I use miktex.

Further, the editor [inlage](http://www.inlage.com/home) can list all the packages installed in your system as in the following image.
[image]
But inlage is only for windows.

> I have found the package, but don't know how to use it.

1. From command prompt/terminal, type `texdoc <package name>` For example `texdoc geometry`. The manual comes up. Almost every package is accompanied with a manual. In rare cases, if it is not the case, try to locate the source file (usually a file with `.sty` extension). Most of times, these source files will have comments at the top.appropriate places on how to use.
2. Your editor may also have a provision to open help files. 
   In texmaker, it looks like this:
   [image] 
   And in `texshop`:
   [image]
   Kile has this elaborate menu:
   [image]
   Finally winedt:
   [image]

Hope this will be helpful. Happy TeXing :-)